# Node.JS: Alternative to chown string

Tags: node.js, unix, chown, chgrp

At this time, [`fs.chown` requires `int` values for `uid` and `gid`](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4410).

So, what is the recommended way to get these int values from a UNIX-like system?

Should I read `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` directly?
That does not seem like the right way to do it...

Comment: The answer for this is going to be OS and even distro-specific.  In machines running the GNU userland, `/usr/bin/getent` is going to be the best way to get user and group info, as it will properly read from external authentication sources, for example.  If you ever find yourself on a BSD or a Solaris, the answer may well be very different...

Answer (score 2):

You've probably solved it by now, but for future reference: the [uid-number](https://npmjs.org/package/uid-number) package is used by npm, so I think it can be safely assumed that it works (and it does for me).

Answer (score 2):

Just call `chown` directly:

```
var exec = require( "child_process" ).exec;
exec( "chown user:group filename" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked and found this: https://npmjs.org/package/getuid
I haven't used it. caveat emptor.

Personally, I like looking these up in a configuration file that the user supplies :)

-daniel